# Hadoop Cluster Hardware: Few large vs many small

Tags: hardware, hadoop

we are looking for some help deciding what hardware to buy to support an internal Hadoop cluster. My company currently uses 1 dedicated server for Hadoop which has 196GB ram and 24cores and 6 1TB SATA hard drives. We are wanting to scale up our capacity but are unsure what to buy for the best value. We are looking to spend around £10k on equipment and have considered blades such as dell PE m710 where we can get 8 blades each with 12 cores, 288 GB ram and 4x600 GB SAS drives with enclosure for our budget. Is this a good use of the money available or would better spec newer servers be more appropriate?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

> dell PE m710 where we can get 8 blades each with 12 cores, 288 GB ram and 4x600 GB SAS drives

- Hadoop node should be cheap(supermicro for example) and have 2U size.
- 600 GB SAS - bad choice. You need something like 12x4GB SATA 7200rpm w/o RAID
- The most important thing is a network. You should use 10Ge or 1G with Bonding.

Please read this:
https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-select-the-right-hardware-for-your-new-hadoop-cluster/

Comment: thanks for the reply and I agree that more disks would be better however we are using this mainly for spark which is memory + cpu once you've read in the data. As per the cloudera doc the 'compute intensive' machine rec we are thinking more memory and fewer disks.

Comment: Does anyone have a similar use case where they would be happy to share their set up?